# Get file path of file uploaded using dropzone

Tags: codeigniter, dropzone.js

How to get the file path of a file uploaded using dropzone in CodeIgniter?

My View page is

```
 <form action="<?php echo site_url('Upload/imageUploadPost');?>" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                                <div class="fallback">
                                    <input name="userfile" type="file"/>
                                </div>
</form>
```

My Controller is

```
public function imageUploadPost()
    {

                $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
        $config['max_size']      = 1024;


                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('file');
//here I need to fetch the uploaded file details like name ,path
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Use `$this->upload->data();` after upload successful to get the file details, Your method should be like this ::*

```
public function imageUploadPost()
{
    //print_r($_FILES);die;
    $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
    $config['max_size']      = 1024;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        /* for full file path use $data['full_path'] and so like this */
        $file_path = $data['full_path'];
        echo $file_path ;
        var_dump($data);
        die();  
    }
    else
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        var_dump($error);
        die();
    }
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: it shows the error array(1) { ["error"]=> string(43) "
You did not select a file to upload.

" }

Comment: but file is uploading to the folder

Comment: i am using dropzone form action

Comment: use `print_r($_FILES);die;` in your `imageUploadPost` method to make sure u have file variable

Comment: it only displays Array ( )

Comment: make sure u have loaded all file related to dropzone : and select file as it said

Comment: it is *impossible* that the file is "uploading" if you are only getting `Array()`

Comment: yes file is uploading,am using dropzonejs for upload,please see my code in the question

Comment: if you r getting $_FILES empty then how is it uploading it means there is not need of upload code in `imageUploadPost` method see this : https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-check-a-checkbox-is-checked-or-not-using-jquery.php

Comment: again the files variable... in all circumstances (except one where you are uploading a base64 image or something) will have to have *something* i.e. not be empty for an image to upload. perhaps the file once uploaded.. delete it. try again. if it appears then its a *ghost in the machine*